# How to fetch data using Nodejs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and using expressjs,Right now i want to get data from datbase(mysql) but i am getting following error

```
"await is only valid for async function"
```

How can i resolve this, here is my current code

```
static async sendOtp(phone_number) {
        var otp=Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9999);
        var config = {
        method: 'get',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          url: 'http://2factor.in/API/V1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/SMS/+91XXXXXXXXXX/12345/XXXXXXXX',
          headers: { }
        };
        axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            
            const sql = "SELECT phoneNumber FROM verifyOtp WHERE phoneNumber = '${phone_number}'";
            const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql);
            console.log('total rows are '+ rows);
            if(rows>0)
            {
                //further logic 1
            }
            else
            {
                //further logic 2
            }
         })
        .catch(function (error) {
          return 'error';
        });

    }
```

Comment: What's unclear from the error message? Your `.then` callback is **not** `async`. And there's no point making the _outer_ function `async` if you're going to use `.then`/`.catch` in it instead of `await`. Pick one or the other, mixing and matching will only lead to confusion. Also note that you don't currently _return_ the promise so the other chain is unrelated to the inner one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is the right solution ? if possible then please post your answer so i can check

Comment: The solution is to read up on the syntax you're trying to use, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. Without a basic understanding of how to interact with promises everything is going to be very difficult.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you post the "updated answer" please ?

Comment: No, I'm not going to rewrite the code for you. Read the error, research the message, read my comments, read the docs. Then you'll be able to rewrite it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

You can handle promise in 2 ways, using `then` or `await`.
It is a good coding practice to use one of them in the whole codebase identically. I recommend you use `async`, `await` structure more so that you can keep code structure clearly. And you need to attach `async` before function name when defining to use `await`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Only `async` the *inner* function

Does this work?

```
static sendOtp(phone_number) {  // <------------   REMOVED `ASYNC` HERE
        var otp=Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9999);
        var config = {
        method: 'get',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          url: 'http://2factor.in/API/V1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/SMS/+91XXXXXXXXXX/12345/XXXXXXXX',
          headers: { }
        };
        axios(config)
        .then(async function (response) { // <-------------- ADDED `ASYNC` HERE
            
            const sql = "SELECT phoneNumber FROM verifyOtp WHERE phoneNumber = '${phone_number}'";
            const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql);
            console.log('total rows are '+ rows);
            if(rows>0)
            {
                //further logic 1
            }
            else
            {
                //further logic 2
            }
         })
        .catch(function (error) {
          return 'error';
        });

    }
```